# Gaussian elimination with pivoting python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, equation, algebra

I am trying to make a function that would solve linear equations with Gaussian elimination with pivoting. However I get an error about matrix dimensions even though the dimensions are fine. What might be the problem?
a=np.array([0,2,3],[4,6,7],[2,-3,6])
b=np.array([8,-3,6])

---

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np 

def zad2(a,b):
    n=len(b)
    AB=np.append(a,b,axis=1) 
    x=np.zeros(n)  
    for i in range(n):  
        maks=abs(AB[i][i])
        wiersz=i
        for k in range(i+1,n): 
            if abs(AB[k][i])>maks: 
                maks=abs(AB[k][i])
                wiersz=k
                for l in range(i,n+1): 
                    el=AB[wiersz][l]
                    AB[wiersz][l]=AB[i][l]
                    AB[i][l]=el
         for k in range(i+1,n): 
            ws=AB[k][i]/AB[i][i] 
            for j in range(i,n+1): 
               AB[k][j]-=ws*AB[i][j]

    for i in range(n-1,-1,-1): 
        x[i]=AB[i][n]/AB[i][i]
        for k in range(i - 1, -1, -1):
            AB[k][n] -= AB[k][i] * x[i]
    return x
```

so I get : 
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, to help the community provide you answers to your problem, you should copy and paste the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: Also provide a small sample of data (And code that loads it) that shows the problem

Comment: Is there a reason why you required 4-levels of for loops (i.e. i, k, l, m)?  Wouldn't this have a complexity O(n^4)? But,  Gaussian elimination has a complexity of O(n^3).  You could compare to [this](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Python) solution.

Answer (score 0):

had to modify few of the lines to get it working. Most of it was correct though. Btw, I'm assuming the array elements are of type float to preserve the fractional values of co-efficients. Also, I have skipped merging the two arrays into one. Though you can make the change if desirable. Logically it makes no difference.

1. After discovering the max column (weirsz in polish I believe), you
   are not using it later, but using k. I changed the lines to use weirsz.
2. You are swapping every row every time a new max is found. I've pushed this for loop out to swap only once per column. (I believe this is the loop hinted at by @DarryIG) And swapping only if the row is not in the right place already.
3. The third nested forloop had row and column indices interchanged, so fixed it.
4. The last for loop also had the index issue. Also, I didn't want to alter the computed matrix entries, so using a temp variable instead.

Hope this helps!

```
import numpy as np 

def zad2(a,b):
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print("Len:{0} Shape:{1}".format(len(a),a.shape))
    print("Len:{0} Shape:{1}".format(len(b),b.shape))
    n=len(b)
    x=np.zeros(n, dtype='f')

    for i in range(n):
        maks=abs(a[i,i])
        wiersz=i
        print("maks: ",maks)
        print("i: ",i)

        for k in range(i+1,n): 
            print("Searching Max row value for the a column: row_i (k): {0}, a[k,i]: {1}".format(k, a[k,i]))
            if abs(a[k,i])>maks:
                maks=abs(a[k,i])
                wiersz=k 
        if wiersz != i:
            a[wiersz], a[i] = (a[i].copy(),a[wiersz].copy()) # Swapping entire row at once
            b[i], b[wiersz] = (b[wiersz], b[i]) # Swapping entire row at one

        for k in range(i+1,n): #tworzenie macierzy trojkatnej 
            print('k: {0}, a[k,i]: {1}, a[i,i]: {2}'.format(k, a[k,i], a[i,i]))
            ws=a[k,i]/a[i,i] #wspolczynnik taki jak przy zwyklej metodzie Gaussa
            for j in range(i,n): #dla kolejnego wiersza eliminacja, wzor z zadania 1
                a[k,j]=a[k,j]- ws*a[i,j]
            b[k]=b[k]-ws*b[i]
        print("i: {0}, maks: {1}, wiersz: {2}".format(i,maks,wiersz))
        print(a)
        print(b)
        input()
    x[n-1] = b[n-1]/a[n-1,n-1]
    for i in range(n-1,-1,-1): #substytucja od konca
        temp = b[i]
        for k in range(i+1,n):
            temp -= a[i,k]*x[k]
        x[i] = (tem)/a[i,i]
    return x

a=np.array([[0,2,3],[4,6,7],[2,-3,6]], dtype='f')
b=np.array([8, -3, 6], dtype='f')

print(zad2(a,b))
```